# Powerpoint Morph slide transition handles images on same slide differently

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

I am making a Powerpoint, and I am seeing this strange behaviour with the morph transition.
I have copied a slide containing two images and replaced both with similar images, which just have some overlay. Both are cropped before and after.

During the transition the first image blends directly into the next one, while the second image first blends to white and then to the next one.

See here:
https://i.imgur.com/FlFQlna.mp4

The morph transition is set for objects. I am using PowerPoint 2302.

Why is it doing that?

Comment: Can you post these two slides in the cloud and link to them from here so interested folks can have a look at the original PPTX?

Comment: I added the file link!

Comment: Thanks for the link. PowerPoint is odd about what it considers identical shape names and that seems to be what's causing this problem. There's a way of *forcing* it to accept two shapes as being the same (for Morphing purposes). Name each shape !!xyz, where xyz is the actual shape name. Once I added !! to the front of each of your picture shape names, the Morph worked, no white flash..

Comment: It also worked for me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. I've copy/pasted my comment into an answer below in case you'd like to mark it as an answer (to help other people find the same solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the link.

PowerPoint is odd about what it considers identical shape names and that seems to be what's causing this problem.

There's a way of forcing it to accept two shapes as being the same (for Morphing purposes):

Use the Selection Pane to name each shape !!xyz, where xyz is the actual shape name. Once I added !! to the front of each of your picture shape names, the Morph worked, no white flash.